# handle firebase data changes without adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a kotlin app of ListView of items from firebase.
The app can insert items to the firebase and everything works great with simple array adapter.

BUT what if I need to do that without using simple array adapter?

In the data class I have `toString()` and I need to use it without the simple adapter

```
data class Product(var name:String, var quantity: Int, var size: String, var comment:String){
    private var _ky:String = ""

    constructor() : this("", 0, "", "")

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "%s, %d, %s\n%s".format(this.name,this.quantity,this.size,this.comment)
    }

    fun fillKey(ky:String) {
        this._ky = ky
    }

    fun giveKey():String {
        return this._ky
    }
}
```

In the activity I have this

```
val products = ArrayList<Product>()
val adptr: ArrayAdapter<Product> by lazy {ArrayAdapter<Product>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, products)}
```

But I don't know what to do with this if I don't use an adapter

```
lvItems.adapter = adptr
lvItems.choiceMode = ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE

myRef.child("products").addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
    override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
        val p: Product = snapshot.getValue(Product::class.java) as Product
        p.fillKey(snapshot.key!!)
        products.add(p)
        adptr.notifyDataSetChanged()
        lvItems.smoothScrollToPosition(products.size - 1)
```

I need to do make it work without an adapter because of my mentor decision.

Comment: What would you like to use if not an adapter?

Comment: You will have to use a certain adapter with list like view i.e. `ListView` and `RecyclerView`, like an `ArrayAdapter` or a `RecyclerView.Adapter`. The second one is mostly used though

Comment: @gtxtreme I actually do have ListView and ArrayAdapter but with them, I have to use the "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked" which is a simple adapter, 
Am I wrong? (would be very happy if I am wrong)

Comment: You're right, you can customise that layout too, but then you'll have to create your own ArrayAdapter subclass with custom inflation logic.

Comment: Also you should consider switching to `RecyclerView` because it has more optimised stuff under the hood i.e. recycling views and support for animations